# How to seal a leak in a plastic tubing connection?

Tags: leak, plastic

I am trying to repair a leak in the plastic tubing pictured.  This tubing is connected to an air conditioner's condensate pump (water runs through it whenever the pump turns on).

The leak is occurring right at the junction between the brown tube and the clear tube - somewhere near/behind the metal collar.  What is the simplest way to fix this leak?

[image: Plastic tubing connection]

Comment: If there is enough slack, or you can replace the whole section of bad tubing, I would. It also looks like the hose it not all the way up on the barb. That is possibly part of the problem. Is it JUST leaking from around the fitting, or dripping down the length of the hose.

Comment: That is a good question.  In fact, when the pump turns on, water shoots everywhere, so it is hard to tell exactly what part is leaking.

Comment: Try loosening the clamp, and pushing the brownish tube onto the plastic fitting until it bottoms out (might require some persuasion).  Then tighten the clamp back down.

Comment: With how yellow the leaking part i would worry this may be a continuing problem without new tubing and a barb connector. It appears that some of the tubing has been replaced now would be a good time to finish replacing it it is only a few bucks and then you will have years of service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tester101 for the answer (in the comments): the brown tube just needed to be pushed back into the clear one.  Fixed!